# ES6 React istanbul No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, istanbul

I have an issue when running my tests the code coverage doesn't work, I have the message

> No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information

I write my tests using ES6 and I use babel to transform the code.

To solve the problem I use the github project provided in this discussion: https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/496

The trick is to use

```
`babel-node ./node_modules/istanbul/lib/cli cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- --require test-helper.js --bail --recursive 'src/js/__tests__/**/*.test.js'`
```

instead of

```
"istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- --compilers js:babel-core/register --require scripts/test-helper.js --recursive 'src/js/__tests__/**/*.test.js'"
```

It works well but the problem is that the code coverage is only considering the classes you have tested, not all the classes you created.

If I add a new class `mod.js` in the `src` folder of the project, the coverage is 100% for the `app.js` component. This is logical because it is fully tested but in the report the `mod.js` class doesn't appear on the report - it is not listed as class with 0% tested (https://github.com/JakeSidSmith/istanbul-no-coverage).

I tried to add the `cover -x 'src/js/__tests__/**/*.test.js'` but doesn't work. I cannot mix mix the first style with the second.

Another problem is that in the project example provided above the test-helper.js is considered as fully tested and i cannot exclude it from the coverage using `cover -x` .

Is there another trick to have right code coverage using ES6/mocha and having mocha call `babel-core/register`?

Comment: I have also this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also faced the same problem but this github [issue](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/262) guided well. I hope you can use use `istanbul@1.0.0-alpha.2` which solved the problem for me.

and my command goes like this `istanbul cover --dir ./coverage _mocha -- ./tests/**/**/*.js --opts ./tests/mocha.opts -R spec`

Comment: True. This solves my issue. Here is my command >> istanbul cover --color ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- -R spec --recursive test/*.js --require babel-core/register --color